# Gradient Descent algorithm raises valueError

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I have these gradient descent algorithm for multivariate regression but it raises an

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (3,140).
```

I checked out other answers on broadcasting errors on stackoverflow and the documentation which says the dimensions of the matrices must be same or either of the matrix must be 1.But how can i make my theta of the same dimension.

Please don't mark it duplicate.

My x has dim (140,3) , y has (140,1), alpha=0.0001

```
def find_mse(x,y,theta):
    return np.sum(np.square(np.matmul(x,theta)-y))*1/len(x)       



def gradientDescent(x,y,theta,alpha,iteration):
    theta=np.zeros(x.shape[1])
    m=len(x)
    gradient_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['coeffs','mse'])

    for i in range(iteration):
        gradient = (1/m) * np.matmul(x.T, np.matmul(x, theta) - y)
        theta = np.mat(theta) - alpha * gradient
        cost = compute_cost(X, y, theta)
        gradient_df.loc[i] = [theta,cost]

    return gradient_df
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; it is impossible for us to help simply by reading your code, please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Which line specifically throws the error?

Comment: 2nd line in the loop....which is generating the error. theta=theta-alpha*gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are multiplying `x` with shape `(140, 3)` with `theta` to produce output which should have shape `(140, 1)`. To achieve this your `theta` should have shape of `(3, 1)`. You need to initialize `theta` as following

```
theta = np.zeros((x.shape[1], y.shape[1]))
```

Comment: Fortunately it worked out .But I didn't get where the problem was can u please explain a bit. I'm a newbie in the field.

Comment: It follows from the properties of matrix multiplication. To multiply 2 matrices A and B, A must have the same number of column as the number of row in B.